# Incorrect Sum by Groupby Dataframe on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Scenario:** After generating a dataframe by concatenating a dict of dataframes, I want to groupy the result given 2 columns, and output the sum.

**Dataframe:** testoutput2

```
+-----+-------+---------+-----------+--------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Key | Index | Level 4 | IEA WEM22 | Region IEA Level 1 | 2018 IEA | 2019 IEA | 2020 IEA | 2021 IEA |
+-----+-------+---------+-----------+--------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| FRA |     - |  12,000 |    12,000 | Advanced economies |       54 |       37 |       26 |     0.00 |
| FRA |     1 |  11,000 |    11,000 | Advanced economies |        8 |        8 |        7 |       11 |
| FRA |     3 |  31,100 |    31,100 | Advanced economies |        4 |        3 |        3 |     0.00 |
| BEL |     - |  12,000 |    12,000 | Advanced economies |        8 |        9 |        7 |     0.00 |
| BEL |     1 |  11,000 |    11,000 | Advanced economies |        1 |        1 |        1 |        2 |
| BEL |     3 |  31,100 |    31,100 | Advanced economies |        1 |        1 |        1 |     0.00 |
+-----+-------+---------+-----------+--------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

**Wanted output:** A dict of dataframes, where each key is an Year. The content of a dataframe inside the dict would be:

```
key 2018 IEA

+---------+--------------------+-----+
| Level 4 | Region IEA Level 1 | Sum |
+---------+--------------------+-----+
|  12,000 | Advanced economies |  62 |
|  11,000 | Advanced economies |   9 |
|  31,100 | Advanced economies |   5 |
+---------+--------------------+-----+
```

**Issue:** When running the code below, I get an incorrect result, where the sums are not the expected values:

```
+---------+--------------------+-----+
| Level 4 | Region IEA Level 1 | Sum |
+---------+--------------------+-----+
|  12,000 | Advanced economies |  61 |
|  11,000 | Advanced economies |   8 |
|  31,100 | Advanced economies |   4 |
+---------+--------------------+-----+
```

**Obs:** I am currently testing this code with a smaller snippet of data (as per the example here). However, the objective is to run this with a much larger dataset. In this case, there is only one entry in the region column, whereas in the main dataset there are more.

**Code:**

```
scen_name = "IEA"
scen_reg_out_dict={}
year_list_2 = [2018,2019,2020,2021]
for year_var in year_list_2:
    scen_reg_out_dict[str(year_var) + " " + scen_name] = testoutput2.groupby(['Level 4','Region IEA Level 1'])[str(year_var) + " " + scen_name].agg(['sum']).astype('int64')
```

**Question:** What could be causing the calculation to fail?

Comment: Can you provide the sample input data in a format we can use when testing?

Comment: Not sure what you left out... when I run your code, I get the expected answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine for me, you could also avoid repeating the grouping with:

```
year_list_2 = [2018,2019,2020,2021]
scen_name = "IEA"
cols = [f'{y} {scen_name}' for y in year_list_2]
group = ['Level 4','Region IEA Level 1']

# set up grouper
g = df.groupby(group, as_index=False)

# reuse the grouper in a dictionary comprehension
scen_reg_out_dict = {c: g[c].sum() for c in cols}
```

Output:

```
{'2018 IEA':   Level 4  Region IEA Level 1  2018 IEA
 0  11,000  Advanced economies         9
 1  12,000  Advanced economies        62
 2  31,100  Advanced economies         5,
 '2019 IEA':   Level 4  Region IEA Level 1  2019 IEA
 0  11,000  Advanced economies         9
 1  12,000  Advanced economies        46
 2  31,100  Advanced economies         4,
 '2020 IEA':   Level 4  Region IEA Level 1  2020 IEA
 0  11,000  Advanced economies         8
 1  12,000  Advanced economies        33
 2  31,100  Advanced economies         4,
 '2021 IEA':   Level 4  Region IEA Level 1  2021 IEA
 0  11,000  Advanced economies      13.0
 1  12,000  Advanced economies       0.0
 2  31,100  Advanced economies       0.0}
```

If you want the grouper as index, @QuangHoang suggested this nice alternative:

```
year_list_2 = [2018,2019,2020,2021]
scen_name = "IEA"
cols = [f'{y} {scen_name}' for y in year_list_2]
group = ['Level 4','Region IEA Level 1']
scen_reg_out_dict = {**df.groupby(group)[cols].sum()}
```

Output:

```
{'2018 IEA': Level 4  Region IEA Level 1
 11,000   Advanced economies     9
 12,000   Advanced economies    62
 31,100   Advanced economies     5
 Name: 2018 IEA, dtype: int64,
 '2019 IEA': Level 4  Region IEA Level 1
 11,000   Advanced economies     9
 12,000   Advanced economies    46
 31,100   Advanced economies     4
 Name: 2019 IEA, dtype: int64,
 '2020 IEA': Level 4  Region IEA Level 1
 11,000   Advanced economies     8
 12,000   Advanced economies    33
 31,100   Advanced economies     4
 Name: 2020 IEA, dtype: int64,
 '2021 IEA': Level 4  Region IEA Level 1
 11,000   Advanced economies    13.0
 12,000   Advanced economies     0.0
 31,100   Advanced economies     0.0
 Name: 2021 IEA, dtype: float64}
```

Comment: The last two rows might be just `out = {**df.groupby(group)[cols].sum()}`?

Comment: @Quang yes of course, I'll add this! Thanks :) (This only works with `as_index=True` though)

Answer (score 2):

Your code give me the expected output. So, I'll just give an alternative :

```
# `df` instead of `testoutput2` for the sake of clarify

gby = df.groupby(["Level 4", "Region IEA Level 1"], as_index=False, sort=False)

scen_reg_out_dict = {
    col: gby[col].sum() for col in df.filter(regex="\d+ IEA").columns
}
```

Output :

```
print(scen_reg_out_dict)

{'2018 IEA':    Level 4  Region IEA Level 1  2018 IEA
 0    12000  Advanced economies        62
 1    11000  Advanced economies         9
 2    31100  Advanced economies         5,
 '2019 IEA':    Level 4  Region IEA Level 1  2019 IEA
 0    12000  Advanced economies        46
 1    11000  Advanced economies         9
 2    31100  Advanced economies         4,
 '2020 IEA':    Level 4  Region IEA Level 1  2020 IEA
 0    12000  Advanced economies        33
 1    11000  Advanced economies         8
 2    31100  Advanced economies         4,
 '2021 IEA':    Level 4  Region IEA Level 1  2021 IEA
 0    12000  Advanced economies    0.0000
 1    11000  Advanced economies   13.0000
 2    31100  Advanced economies    0.0000}
```

Comment: Haha, similar idea :p

Comment: I'm doing my best haha ;)